# Flutter Slider (seekbar) - how to make it shorter in length?

Tags: flutter

I have a Row widget - within this, I want a slider (as a seek bar for audio) and on the left and right I want labels for the times, as well as a play button, and 2 more icon buttons for share etc. all this is making the row overflow. Is there some way to make the slider shorter in length?

Comment: have you explored any tutorial of it? if yes then please share code for the same.

Comment: Can you add some code, so that we can check where it's going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will be expand slide widget remain area.

```
Row(
   children: <Widget> [
      Expanded(child: Slider(value: 5, onChanged: null)),
      YourButtonWidget(),
      YourButtonWidget(),
      YourButtonWidget(),
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the slider in a container and change the width/height of the container.

```
Container(
  width: 50,
  child: Slider(value: 5, onChanged: null),
),
```